# Simplifying conditions inside probability calculations with a standard normal random variable

Tags: normal-distribution

What is $P(Z^2 < 1)$? I'm not sure what I'm doing.

I am thinking that the way to do this is just apply algebra inside the probability operator and find $P(Z<1)$ by the complement rule. $(1-P(Z > 1))=(1 - .1587)=.8413$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your idea that you can perform algebraic manipulations inside $P()$ to simplify the calculation is correct.

Your execution of the idea is not correct.

You had $Z^2<1$  and replaced that with $Z<1$. That's not the same as what you started with, because $Z$ can be negative. Consider $Z=-2$. It's not true that $Z^2<1$, but it is true that $Z<1$ (i.e. you're including probability you should not be including.

You have to be careful to keep only the same region for $Z$ as you perform manipulations on the condition. (What values of $Z$ will have $Z^2<1$? Try some values like -3, -1/2, 0, 1/4, 1, 2 and think about how it must work)

Once you rewrite the term suitably you should be able to work the answer out.